How to give sharing access to role / roles and subordinates via apex sharing
I was trying to give lookup Id of a role to custom object share record via below code
List<UserRole> role = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE Name = 'CFO' LIMIT 1];
custObj__Share custObj  = new custObj__Share();
custObj.ParentId = 'a0DJ2000000Ke4T';
custObj.UserOrGroupId = role[0].Id;
custObj.AccessLevel = 'Read';
insert custObj;

but I got this error

So I just queried the existing share records of that custom object and copied the userorgroupId field value for a record that gave read access to the role for some other record via manual sharing. I used this copied value as hardcoded value for the userOrGroupId field in my above code and it worked this time! So I was able to share a record to a role via apex by giving the copied value I took from existing share object record.
This was the actual value of cfo userrole 00E5h00000157jt.
This value was giving "id value of incorrect type exception"
I updated the code to this
custObj.UserOrGroupId = '00G5h000004vmHtEAI'; //copied id from existing share record

I was able to give read / read write access via this code to the users of that role.
I Infact copied value for roles and subordinate as well to share records with those roles and subordinate and this also worked
custObj.UserOrGroupId = '00G5h000004vmHtEAI';

The documentation for that field states it can be either a lookup to user or public group but my code experiment suggests that we can use apex for sharing records with specific roles or roles and subordinates as well

Only problem is how to find the correct Id value for roles or roles and subordinates for the field as the correct Id value gives field integrity exception.What is missing in my understanding

The share record requires you to share with a user or group.
The hard coded Ids you're sharing with are Group ids, which you can tell based on the 00G prefix, but the id you're trying to use is a UserRole id based on the 00E prefix.
You need to get the related group from your query.  Something like:
SELECT Id FROM Group 
WHERE RelatedId IN 
     (SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE WHERE Name = 'CFO' LIMIT 1) 
AND Type = 'Role'


Thanks that worked. I just come to know that whenever we create a role , Salesforce creates two group record for same one with type as 'Role' and another with type as 'RoleAndSubordinates' . Basically every role record has two associated record in Group . One for Role and another for RoleAndSubordinates type
